# Synchronize Remote Git repository with web server

Tags: git, web, synchronization

I have a website I am working on with git as version control. However, it is becoming annoying to have to manually update the web server with changes to our code as well as the git repository every time we want to make a commit. Is it possible, perhaps with third-party software, to synchronize my git repository with the public website, such that whenever I make a commit to the repository, the website will be automatically updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is called an automated build, or Continuous Integration.  There are many tools that allow you to do this, but it's hard to recommend one without knowing your development platform ([TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), my favorite, works with git and many development platforms).

Depending on what your website is for, it's generally risky to push code out into production on each commit.  Usually the process is more controlled than that.

Comment: What do you mean by development platform? IDE? OS?

Comment: OS probably factors in, but more along the lines of whether you are using java, .Net, PHP, etc.  TeamCity covers all of these and others, and I'm sure their competitors do as well.

Comment: Oh, PHP and javascript most likely

Comment: With Git, there are multiple ways you could set it up so that you only push to production when you want to, not on every commit. But personally I'm trying to figure out how to run a static web site such that I don't have to manually upload the content to an FTP server every time it changes... pushing to the web site on every commit is exactly what I want.